# Interacting with buttons/macros inside excel automatically

Tags: python, excel, pywinauto

I'm trying to find a way to make a python script that finds all the buttons/checkboxes inside an excel document and interacts with them randomly.

I've tried using pywinauto, but it doesn't find the actual objects inside the document (probably because it's a vb object and not a regular GUI).

How can it be done using python? Or maybe there's another way to do it?

Here is a file for example [excel](https://ufile.io/7rboc)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a sample Excel table with some dummy data?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Here is a sample: https://ufile.io/7rboc

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the sample! I'm afraid there is no nice way to obtain button or check box texts using pywinauto. Though `Inspect.exe` shows these controls but they all are just images! See [the screenshot with Inspect.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxXsh.png). So the only way to automate them is enumerating by index. Of course, you must use `pywinauto.Application(backend="uia")`. For random interaction the texts might not matter, but the texts would be very helpful for re-contructing the actions sequence in case of crash/error.

Another chance might be in `win32com.client` usage. Not sure Excel COM objects have necessary properties. Need to investigate separately.